# Reuse Devise authentication for custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

I am trying to create a custom controller in the admin section of Spree and reuse the devise authentication mechanism. How do I go about doing this. I have simply tried to do the following:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class WorkflowController < Spree::Admin::BaseController
    end
  end
end
```

And I created a route like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :workflow, :only => [:index, :show]
end
```

I am getting the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin):

So, any thoughts on how to best create a custom controller or am I just doing something wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your controller is nested inside the `Spree` namespace, but your routes are not. If you want to extend Spree's routes, then do this:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :workflow, :only => [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that and I am still getting:  No route matches [GET] "/admin/workflow"

Comment: The route is at wherever you mounted Spree. Check `rake routes` for that.